# mysql joins to return perfect result

Tags: mysql

I have bought two courses VLSI electronics and VLSI extc which were
bought together so it has same order id
The query returns result when we searched for vlsi or electronics but
doesn't result anything when search in the filterextc.

```
 SELECT  `i.*,r.emailid,r.first_name,u.university_name,ct.country_name,st.state_name, cy.city_name,r.address,r.mobile,COUNT( k.order_id ) as order_cnt, k.product_type AS product_type,k.product_id AS product_id,tx.tax_amount,str.stream_name,fie.field_name,sems.semester_number,colg.college_name,`
    IF( product_type =  "course", (SELECT course_title FROM tbl_courses WHERE course_id = product_id  AND course_title Like "%vlsi%"), 0 ) AS coursebought,
     IF(product_type = "module",(SELECT module_title FROM tbl_modules WHERE module_id = product_id ), 0 ) AS modulebought  
      FROM (`tbl_orders` AS i)
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_users AS r ON  i.user_id =  r.user_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_discount_history AS hd ON  i.order_id =  hd.order_id
                      AND i.discount_id = hd.discount_id
                      AND hd.status =  "Active"
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_shopping_cart AS k ON  i.order_id = k.order_id 
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_university AS u ON  u.university_id =  r.university_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_country AS ct ON  u.country_id =  ct.country_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_states AS st ON  u.state_id =  st.state_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_city AS cy ON  u.city_id =  cy.city_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_finalorder_tax_details AS tx ON  i.order_id =  tx.order_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_stream AS str ON  r.stream_id =  str.stream_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_fields AS fie ON  r.field_id  =  fie.field_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_semester_type AS sems ON  r.semester_id  =  sems.semester_id
                      LEFT JOIN  tbl_colleges AS colg ON  r.college_id  =  colg.college_id
                      and ct.country_id =  cy.city_country_id
                      and st.state_id =  cy.city_state_id
                      WHERE tx.tax_id = 1 and r.status =  "Active" And 1=1   AND product_id IS NOT NULL 
                      AND product_type =  "course"
                      GROUP BY order_id 
                      having coursebought IS NOT NULL and modulebought IS NOT NULL 
                      ORDER BY  order_id  desc 
                      limit 0,10
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if there is order id 2 and in that order two courses are bought (vlsi electronics and vlsi extc) so it searches one since we have done group by order id , i want to group by it but filter both